# Cannot resize Ubuntu partition with GParted (not extended partition)

Tags: gparted

This is strange, but for some reason, I cannot resize Ubuntu partitions using GParted.
I can resize/move partition with Fedora, ElementaryOS, but not Ubuntu (in my case /sdb3 and /sdb2).

I don't have extended partitions.

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu partitions must be unmounted to be worked on.  Usually done with a live USB.  Can also do from another Linux OS.  Do not know how Fedora and Elementary works.  If Ubuntu is unmounted, edit info in your question.

Comment: Might also need to move partitions around before resizing, to make room.

Comment: I'll unmount it, and tell you if it helps.
I moved partitions already, there is enough space around it.

Comment: @karel, no, I don't have extended partitions

Comment: @crip659, unmounting helped - I could successfully resize my partitions! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks go to [crisp659](https://askubuntu.com/users/431265/crip659) who commented with the solution.

> Ubuntu partitions must be unmounted to be worked on. Usually done with a live USB. Can also do from another Linux OS. Do not know how Fedora and Elementary works. If Ubuntu is unmounted, edit info in your question.

– [crip659](https://askubuntu.com/users/431265/crip659) [2 days ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251691/cannot-resize-ubuntu-partition-with-gparted-not-extended-partition/1252246#comment2113124_1251691)

> Might also need to move partitions around before resizing, to make room.

– [crip659](https://askubuntu.com/users/431265/crip659) [2 days ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251691/cannot-resize-ubuntu-partition-with-gparted-not-extended-partition/1252246#comment2113143_1251691)

I unmounted Ubuntu's partition, and after that I was able to resize/move it.